# PHP - check if key in multidimensional array is true or false

Tags: php, angularjs, webforms

I'm trying to set the value of a variable based on three booleans from a multidimensional array but I'm having trouble accessing it. I'm kinda new to PHP and Javascript.

After a var_dump of my form data (passed using $http from angular to an external PHP-file) I'm left with:

```
array(3) {
  ["selectedServices"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["test"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["test2"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["test3"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  ["otherstuff"]=>
  string(10) "coolfield"
  ["smsDelRep"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Now I'm trying to create a variable based on "selectedServices" but all attempts so far has failed, I can't even access it.

Currently this is what I have:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    $selectedServices = array($_POST['selectedServices']);
    if (in_array('test', $selectedServices, true)) {
        $allowedServices = '1';
        var_dump($allowedServices);
```

But I'm not getting the var_dump so I'm guessing the if-statement returns false. But why?

Comment: You want to check for the array key rather than search for the key as a value.

Comment: Why are you wrapping your post in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In_array checks values, not keys, you could do :

```
if(isset($selectedServices['test']) {
  //
}
```

EDIT : This is not a perfect solution, if $selectedServices['test'] is null it will not work

Use array_key_exist instead :

```
if(array_key_exists('test', $selectedServices)) {
  //
}
```

But there is an error in your code :

```
 $selectedServices = array($_POST['selectedServices']);
```

should be

```
$selectedServices = $_POST['selectedServices'];
```

Comment: Hrm, it still becomes false;

if(isset($selectedServices['test']) {
 echo "yay";
else {
echo "nay";
}
}

Gives me "nay" :(